# "Soft" disable webmin

Tags: redhat

Can I "soft" disable webmin without breaking everything? I want to disable just the interface for webmin but not it's services and be able to enable it easily if needed. For security reasons. This is a redhat machine.

Answer (score 4):

Yes - you can soft-disable webmin by shutting down the webmin server.
Webmin's underlying functionality is implemented via standard unix subsystems (like `cron` for scheduling tasks, or the rc boot sequence for starting things when your server boots).

Honestly, if you care about security you should be looking at eliminating webmin from your environment entirely, and managing your systems the way the operating system vendor recommends.

Webmin is a crutch.
If you don't need it you shouldn't use it.
If you do need it, you should work on getting to the point where you don't anymore.